# AWS post request issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, paypal

I have deployed my Flask application on AWS. I am trying to send POST requests from the AWS Flask server to PayPal's REST APIs. Occasionally, the requests fail. This typically happens when I attempt to send a request after a day or two. When the request fails, I resolve the issue by restarting my AWS server, and everything works smoothly afterward. Could you please help me identify the potential issue, as everything functions correctly after a server restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPal REST API oauth2 access_tokens are valid (and so can be cached and reused) for 9 hours, after which a new one must be obtained (using the client ID and secret)

So if you are only requesting an access_token on startup, that would explain the described behavior

Comment: `def get_result_from_paypal(url):
    for attempt in range(10):
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=paypal_headers)
            response.raise_for_status() 
            if response.status_code == 200:
                result = response.json()
                return result
            else:
                paypal_headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {paypal_token(paypal_client_id, paypal_client_secret, paypal_api_url)}'
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print(f"Error fetching PayPal API: {e}")
        time.sleep(2)`

Comment: is it a right way to update the access_token?